# Gather specific data from mysql database and create statistics per week

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a school project where I have a webpage implemented that clients can input restaurant order and then, the order is forwarded to a MySQL database all hosted on a raspberry PI. Now I need to create a type of statistics per week meaning for example how much orders were created per day etc. What are the requirements for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, but given that you tagged PHP in your question, I'll assume that you are trying to accomplish this task using PHP.  If you want the statistics to be displayed on the webpage you would simply:

- Determine the SQL query that returns the results you're looking for
- Develop report template page
- Submit your SQL query through PHP
- Pass variables from result set to the report template page

If you are trying to generate an spreadsheet of the statistics, [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) is a good option

EDIT:  This answer provides a broad overview of what needs to be done to accomplish this task.  Your question was not specific enough to drill down on a single area.